# How do I create a bucket that is easily accessible to all Internet public via a single link?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What I have completed:

1. Permissions/Public access is set to "Public to internet"
2. Access control is set to "fine-grained"

Questions that I need answered:

1. What should Role/Member be set to? Is "Storage Legacy Bucket Reader" correct? If not, what is the name of the Role/Member I should Add?
2. When expanded, this Role/Member reads "Viewers of project: massive-tuner-323301" and "Resource: "all-my-music" (which is where my files will be located). Is this the correct configuration for anyone on the Internet to access and/or download any of the files in that resource? If not, how should this section be configured and how do I do it?
3. How do I create a **single Internet link** that anyone can click in order to immediately be inside that resource/directory, ready to download any file?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question if you only need to set the read only permissions, it’s recommended to set the [Storage Legacy Bucket Reader](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#acls) as you mentioned, regarding your second question, you are right the read only permissions is enough, about the third question, you need to [make all objects in a bucket readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets) to everyone on the public internet, please see an example:

```
gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Finally to [access to your bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data#console) you can access the bucket with:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/BUCKET_NAME
```